# restart computer without root from script

Tags: reboot

When I type

```
reboot
```

I get

```
reboot: Need to be root
```

P.S. I do not have sudo privileges and password

Answer (score 1):

On Debian, you have to be a member of the powerdev group in order to shut the computer down as a regular user. I am not sure how this works in Ubuntu.

What you can do either way is to use the setuid bit in order to allow anyone to reboot the computer. Think about it, before you do this though. Maybe you can only set the setuid for the group of `reboot` and change the group of reboot to your own user group (or create a new power group by hand).

Comment: And if you don't have permissions to make the changes on another account, reboot to recovery mode, select the 'remount' option, and then the 'root' option and do it then you will, but it's probably best to ask the machine admin do do it for you ....

Comment: I can reboot using the GUI (unity?gnome?)

Comment: Yes, since GDM/LightDM is allowed to reboot the computer if nobody else is logged in. But it is not really *you* who shuts it down.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what Ubuntu you're using but to power off the computer try

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Stop
```

and to restart

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit.Manager.Restart
```

For a list of possible actions run

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.ConsoleKit /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Manager org.freedesktop.DBus.Introspectable.Introspect
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
systemctl reboot -i
```

To shutdown run this

```
systemctl poweroff -i
```

to hibernate, suspend, hybrid run

```
systemctl hibernate -i
systemctl suspend -i
systemctl hybrid-sleep -i
```